# windows- python hangs on input() or raw_input()

Tags: windows, input, raw-input

I an doing a project in python in which i need to input a character on the basis of the image flashed and it continues for many files in for loop.But while executing at every raw_input or input program hangs.I have found the same problem in LINUX while searching stack overflow...For me it is in Windows.Plz help me on it or suggest some other alternative to take input form user in for loop.

Answer (score 0):

So I would answer it myself.As i got the answer.

What I was trying to do is to run two processes simultaneously :
1) to flash the image
2) to get input from user..........
so to solve it I used subprocess module.
here is its documentation

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html